# ActiveRecord update association to match new list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a pretty common many-to-many association in my models, each `story` *has_many* `tags`, what I want to do is to be able to update all of the tags of the story in a simple matter. Right now I'm just deleting all relations and writing them again, basically:

```
def update_tags(tag_list)
  self.tags.clear
  tag_list.each { |tag| self.tags << tag }
  save
end
```

But I feel that it's a dirty way to do things, as there a better solution to this issue? Something like

```
self.tags = tag_list
save
```

Although that doesn't work of course :)

EDIT: So the latter works, turns out I was building a list using map, and inside the map block I used a return statement, I removed it and it (using implicit return I guess) and it now works!

Comment: Why does not `self.tags = tag_list` work? Is there a error message it is throwing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-objects

```
def update_tags(tag_list)
  self.tags = tag_list
end
```

This must work.

Comment: Uhm I tried it and it doesn't get updated, I'm just passing an array of AR Objects though...